# How to make a dql query with jointable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I have this entities:

-Entity Frase:

```
/**
* Frase
*
* @Entity
* @Table( name="frase") } )
*
*/
class Frase {

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @Id
 * @GeneratedValue
 * @Column(type="integer")
*/
private $id;

/**
 * @var String
 *
 *@Column(type="string", length=200, name="texto")
*/
private $text;

/**
 * @var Autor
 *
 * @ManyToOne( targetEntity="Autor", inversedBy="frases")
*/
private $autor;

/**
* @var Tema[]
*
* @ManyToMany( targetEntity="Tema", inversedBy="frases",
*   fetch="EAGER", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true
* )
* @JoinTable(
*   name="tema_frase",
*   inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="tema_id", referencedColumnName="tema_id") }
* )
*/
private $tema;
...

/**
* Tema
*
* @Entity
* @Table( name="tema") } )
*
*/
```

-Entity Tema:

```
class Tema {



/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @Id
 * @GeneratedValue
 * @Column(type="integer", name="tema_id")
*/
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @Column(type="string", length=50, name="nombre", unique=true)
*/
private $nombre;

/**
* @var Frase[]
*
* @ManyToMany( targetEntity="Frase", mappedBy="tema" )
*/
private $frases;
```

I need make a query like this in dql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(tema.nombre) as Tema, count(frase.texto)AS 'Nº Frases' FROM tema_frase RIGHT JOIN tema ON tema_frase.tema_id=tema.tema_id LEFT JOIN frase ON frase.id=tema_frase.frase_id GROUP BY tema.nombre
```

But the problem in dql is that I can't access to the table that create doctrine to database called "tema_frase" to make this query.

So, how can I make this query in dql if I need tema_frase?

[image: Tables in my database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
$query = $entityManager->createQuery("

SELECT t.nombre, count(f.text) 
FROM Model\Tema t 
LEFT JOIN t.frases f 
GROUP BY t.nombre"

);

$result = $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your issue correctly, you can use qualify the table name with the database it resides...

```
SELECT DISTINCT(tema.nombre) as Tema, count(frase.texto)AS 'Nº Frases' 
from $tema_frase_db.tema_frase 
LEFT JOIN $frase_db.frase ON frase.id=tema_frase.frase_id 
GROUP BY tema.nombre
```

where $teme_frase_db is the database housing the tema_frase table
and $frase_db is where the frase table resides.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you. What contains the variable $tema_frase?

Comment: You don't specify the databases where the tables are stored... so the $tema_frase_db is represents the database for that table and $frase_db represents the database for the frase table.  Full qualifying the table name allows you to reference tables outside of your default database. Replace the variables with the actual database name.